# Error while creating page on component save and close with multiple user at a time

Tags: 2011, tom.net, component

I am getting an error while creating page on component save and close with multiple user at a time.

Below error i am getting

‘A database error occurred while executing Stored Procedure “EDA_ORG_ITEMS_FINDUNIQUENESSCONFLICTS.”

A database error occurred while executing Stored Procedure "EDA_PUBLICATIONS_READ". Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.

Can you please help.

Comment: Can you update the question or add a tag to include the Content Manager version + service pack + hotfix rollup?

Comment: Hi Elena, I am using SDL Tridion 2011-SP1

Answer (score 2):

(Can't really answer you question, but I'm not allowed to comment on it.) 
What I understand from your question you use the event system to create a page when a user saves a component.

I would look into the logic for how you set the name for the new page and where you store that page, do you have very many pages in the same structure group? (and inheritance down to a lot of publications?)

If that is the case try to put the pages in different structure groups, separate on year/subject depending on type of information.